# How to run different methods in parallel and obtain the outputs for further processing?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

I would like to understand how to run two core intensive functions in parelle. The functions require the same input and produce different outputs.

Last time I used the multiprocessing library, I saved the results to a file and did not need further processing.

Below is a simple example of the type of code. How to parallelize the functions so that both outputs a and b can be used for further processing?
I am using Python 2.7.

```
input_dict = {'key1':'value1','key2':'value2','key3':'value3'}

def func1(dictionary):
    # do some work
    return np.array()

def func2(dictionary):
    # do different work
    return np.array()

a = func1(input_dict)
b = func2(input_dict)

result = np.dot(a, b)
```

Is the code below the correct way to run both functions together and collect their output?

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

input_dict = {'key1':'value1','key2':'value2','key3':'value3'}

def func1(dictionary):
    # do some work
    return q.put(np.array())

def func2(dictionary):
    # do different work
    return q.put(np.array())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    q1 = Queue()
    q2 = Queue()
    p1 = Process(target=func1, args=(input_dict,))
    p2 = Process(target=func2, args=(input_dict,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    a = q1.get()
    b = q2.get()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    result = np.dot(a, b)
```

Comment: Use a queue fed by a file reading thread.

Comment: using 2 queues? I want to keep the two outputs separate and process them together using np.dot(). Can you provide an example? Iv'e read the docs and used the multiprocessing library before however I am confused about this use case.

Comment: ok, perhaps you should phrase your question better. Your first paragraph says "The functions require the same input and produce different outputs". Also, I didn't say 2 queues - I said **a** queue. As it stands, you've shown no effort to parallelise your code. Why don't you progress further then ask a more specific question later?

Comment: I've updated the post with code. Normally I would do a lot more experimenting however the functions take a 3+ hours each to run so it is difficult. I also haven't seen a solution for this use case on stack overflow so this question could become helpful for a few people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's mostly correct, but you have to to pass `q1` and `q2` when initializing the processes.

Also, replace `return q.put(np.array())` with `q.put(np.array())`

When getting the results queue like `a = q1.get()` remember that you are only getting a single item from the queue, not a list.

If you need to extract a list, you can do something like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import numpy as np

input_dict = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}


def func1(dictionary, q):
    # do some work
    for x in xrange(5):
        q.put(
            np.random.randint(2, size=20)
        )
    q.put('STOP')


def func2(dictionary, q):
    # do different work
    q.put(
        np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0,
                  1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    q1 = Queue()
    q2 = Queue()
    p1 = Process(target=func1, args=(input_dict, q1))
    p2 = Process(target=func2, args=(input_dict, q2))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    f1_results = []
    # Keep adding items from func1 to the results list, until it sees a 'STOP' item
    for array in iter(q1.get, 'STOP'):
        f1_results.append(array)

    b = q2.get()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    for a in f1_results:
        result = np.dot(a, b)
        print result
```